# How to make two calls in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular7, ngrx-store

I am trying to make two http call in ngrx Effect. Say I have comments to fetch. It first makes a call to get latest comment and check if it is already present on UI, if not I make a second call and get all the comments. This runs in continuous polling. Here's my code. I am learning angular and Observable are kind confusion right now.

```
@Effect()
fetchAllComments: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(commentsActions.FETCH_ALL_COMMENTS),
    withLatestFrom(this._store),
    mergeMap(([action, state]) => {
        return this._http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/comments/latest`)
            .pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return this._error.handle(error, new commentsActions.FetchAllCommentsError)
                }))
            .subscribe(comment => {
                console.log("Response from server", comment);
                if (!!comment['id'] && state.comment.comments.every(n => n.id !== comment['id'])) {
                    console.log("making call to fetch api ");
                    return this._http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/comment`)
                        .pipe(
                            map((comments: any) => new commentsActions.FetchAllCommentsComplete(comments.message)),
                            catchError(error => {
                                return this._error.handle(error, new commentsActions.FetchAllCommentsError);
                            }));
                } else {
                    console.log("returning mock");
                    return of(state.comment.comments);
                }
            })
    }));
```

Is this the right approach ? I am getting Bunch of errors starting with `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Thank You

Comment: Yeah, may be that's best approach. I am working on adding this one small feature. Basically I am coming from AngularJS background, used only promises so far.

Comment: Reactive programming is one of the greatest advancements of programming in recent times. RxJs is the JS implementation of reactive programming and Angular is built upon it. I jumped into Angular from AngularJs without a good understanding of RxJs and wished someone gave me this advise a few years ago. Make sure you don't do any Angular until you have a good understanding of the fundamentals of RxJs, the code I wrote in my first few projects would be a lot different if I did.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a subscription from a mergeMap, you need to return the observable but you subscribe to it and the subscription is what you are returning.